# How to store image file from input into a variable in js?

Tags: javascript

I take a file input in html

`<input type="file" />`

How can i store the input image into a image object variable?

Comment: What do you want after storing that image? Wanna show? Or send to server?

Comment: are you looking for the image tag from the DOM, or do you want to get the image as a binary file ??

Comment: I want to send the file to the server.

Comment: I want to get the image as binary file.